# Project to tree in EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-3.1

Hey guys we have a tree view scenario (actually we only use two levels but in theory it could have several levels of leafs).

The Entity is pretty complex So i do not want to project the same data twice for DRY reasons. I found this article which is for 2.x

https://benjii.me/2018/01/expression-projection-magic-entity-framework-core/

Using their compile method I was testing this

```
Expression <Func<MyEntity, TempDto>> foo = e => new TempDto
{ 
    dto = factory.Compile().Invoke(e),
    children = e.Children.AsQueryable().Select(factory)
};
```

Note this is not truly recursive, but its a first step of reusing the projection. I event did a first test without the childrne only calling `factory.Compile().Invoke` and I get

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
    at lambda_method(Closure , PaymentTransaction )
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at IC.Eko.Core.DataAccess.Repositories.PaymentRepository.ListUnmatchedPaymentsByAsync(Int32 accountId) in C:\git\Eko\src\IC.Eko.Core.DataAccess\Repositories\PaymentRespository.cs:line 113
   at IC.Eko.Core.CommandHandlers.Payments.MapPaymentsWithInvoicesCommandHandler.Handle(MapPaymentsWithInvoicesCommand command) in C:\git\Eko\src\IC.Eko.Core\CommandHandlers\Payments\MapPaymentsWithInvoicesCommandHandler.cs:line 28
   at IC.Eko.Core.Cqs.Commands.CommandRunner.ExecuteCommand(Func`1 commandFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Nullable`1 id) in C:\git\Eko\src\IC.Eko.Core.Cqs\Commands\CommandRunner.cs:line 256
```

Comment: Is it not possible to query out a flat list with references, then build up the nested object in code?

Comment: I like projections because you do not need to todo include etc. But it seems when doing it like this you need to include anyway (thats why I got null because I didnt include the navigation properties, this is not needed for standard Select(e => new Foo {}) type projectiobns. I do not win alot I think buy using projections